# How to assign IAM Role to implicit API Gateway in SAM template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-serverless

I have an AWS SAM template that creates an explicit lambda and implicit api gateway (via `Events` property). I need to assign specific and different IAM roles to the lambda and api gateway. Whereas the lambda role is self-evident from the SAM template syntax, I cannot figure out how to assign a role to the api gateway.

E.g.

```
# template.yaml
...
Resources:
  MyLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: very-important-lambda
      Handler: src/index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs8.10
      Role: !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/lambda-role-name
      CodeUri: ./build
      # Below event creates an AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi resource, but how do I give that resource an IAM Role?
      Events:
        PostDomainEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Method: POST
            Path: "/path/resource/v1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to add a role to your API Gateway? SAM wil automatically (implicitly) arrange that the API Gateway has permissions to invoke the Lambda functions using the Lambda resource policy (more about that in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apitgateway-method-integration.html) of the API Gateway)

If you want to set a resource policy of the API Gateway or set some other setting, it is possible to explicitly define the API that is used by your Lambda-event.

E.g. setting the resource policy:

```
RestApi:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
  Properties:
    Policy: > 
      {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Principal": {
                        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:root"
                    },
                    "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
                    "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:eu-central-1: 123456789012:7mancjlc5z/*"
                }
            ]
        }

Function:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    Events:
      ApiRequest:
        Type: Api
        Properties:
          Path: /v1/comments
          Method: post
          RestApiId: !Ref RestApi
```

The SAM docs are not totally clear on this but at the moment of writing the above setup works.

Comment: thanks for the help! I will give this a go soon. As for the why the role/policy must be explicit, it's an organizational requirement that I'm bound to.